# Apache RewriteRule only matches if pattern is preceded by equal sign

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite any urls that end on a sequence of numbers and capitalized letters. Unfortunately I have only been partially successful. This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule [A-Z0-9]+$ index.php?r=wizard/index&key=$1 [L]
```

For some reason, this only works for my urls that end on

```
key=QO106A654O65NN6828N
```

If the equal sign is missing from the url like this

```
keyQO106A654O65NN6828N
```

the url is not matched. I don't understand why that equal sign is significant since it's not even part of the regex. What could be causing this behavior?

As requested some example urls that don't work unless an '=' sign is inserted as described above:

```
/index.php?r=wizard/index&id&key4C2918IFIY3U4APKOI1
/index.php?r=wizard/index&id\xEF\xBF\xBD&keyQO106A654O65NN6828N
```

Comment: Can you show some examples of those URLs?

Comment: I've added some examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot match QUERY_STRING using rewrite rule.

Have your rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)key([A-Z0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ $1?r=wizard/index&key=%1 [L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks. However, now the urls without '=' sign are redirected to urls like this
<domain>/<absolute-server-path-to-index.php>?r=wizard/index&key=4C2918IFIY3U4APKOI1&r=wizard/index&id&key4C2918IFIY3U4APKOI1

Comment: Great! that works. Many thanks. I will try to understand this code when I have more time.